# How can I read input values ​written by a user? In PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
  text VARCHAR2(20) := &text;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(text);
END;
```

When I declare this anonymous block so that the user enters a value by keyboard, it shows me an error in the console output.

This is the error:

```
Error starting at line: 3 of the command:
 DECLARE
  text VARCHAR2(20) := Hello;
 START
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(text);
  END;
Bug report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 26:
PLS-00201: identifier 'HELLO' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 10:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 4, column 25:
PLS-00320: The type declaration of this expression is incomplete or has a wrong format.
incorrect
ORA-06550: line 4, column 4:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 - "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause: Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: What client tool are your users using? Client tools that support substitution variables, such as SQL\*Plus and SQL Developer, are normally aimed at technical developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is a substitution variable whose datatype is `varchar2`, enclose it into single quotes (as any other string):

```
SQL> declare
  2    text varchar2(20) := '&text';            --> this
  3  begin
  4    dbms_output.put_line(text);
  5  end;
  6  /
Enter value for text: Hello
old   2:   text varchar2(20) := '&text';
new   2:   text varchar2(20) := 'Hello';
Hello

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this block, you are trying to pass another variable **Hello** (not its value) to the **text** variable.
Use apostrophes to make the compiler interpret it as a value and not as a variable - **'Hello'**

```
DECLARE
  text VARCHAR2(20) := Hello; --<< change to 'Hello'
 START
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(text);
 END;
```

Comment: but what I want is that the user can enter a value by keyboard, how could I do it?

Comment: It depends on how you are passing the parameter. If there is no problem with the disappearance of apostrophes from the passed value (escaping problem), then two simple options can be tried:

1. pass value with apostrophes (look at the difference in this screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGTqK.png)

2. use literal quoting (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#sthref344)